# Design : A Java Application with high throughput

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I have a scenario, in which

1. A HUGE Input file with a specific format, delimited with \n has to be read, it has almost 20 Million records.
2. Each Record has to be read and processed by sending it to server in specific format.

=====================

I am thinking on how to design it.
 
- Read the File(nio)
- The thread that reads the file can keep those chunks into a JMS queue.
- Create n threads representing n servers (to which the data is to be sent). and then n Threads running in parallel can pick up one chunk at a time..execute that chunk by sending requests to the server.

Can you suggest if the above is fine, or you see any flaw(s) :). Also it would be great if you can suggest better way/ technologies to do this.

Thank you!

**Updated**  : I wrote a program to read that file with 20m Records, using Apache Commons IO(file iterator) i read the file in chunks (10 lines at at time). and it read the file in 1.2 Seconds. How good is this? Should i think of going to nio?  (When i did put a log to print the chunks, it took almost 26seconds! )

Comment: Can you further define HUGE? I would suggest starting with the simplest single threaded implementation. You may be surprised by the performance achieved.

Comment: Yes, the file has almost 20 Million Records, Each Record has 10 comma seperated words.

Comment: What do you mean by chunk?

Comment: You should be careful with parallellizing, as it might open a new connection every time, and you do not want to open 100+ connections to a server I guess.

Comment: The entire idea of using the n threads is that i have to got n servers. On top of that having n threads means n connections to n servers. However I still have to think on how to manage the network side..using a connectionfactory or stuff there..

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

20 million records isn't actually that many so first off I would try just processing it normally, you may find performance is fine.

After that you will need to measure things.

You need to read from the disk sequentially for good speed there so that must be single threaded.

You don't want the disk read waiting for the networking or the networking waiting for the disk reads so dropping the data read into a queue is a good idea. You probably will want a chunk size larger than one line though for optimum performance. Measure the performance at different chunk sizes to see.

You may find that network sending is faster than disk reading already. If so then you are done, if not then at that point you can spin up more threads reading from the queue and test with them.

So your tuning factors are:

- chunk size
- number of threads.

Make sure you measure performance over a decent sized amount of data for various combinations to find the one that works best for your circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis. Yes I am sure i will have to reach an optimal value for ChunkSize and Number of Threads. Each call to the server takes almost 200ms. 

I am still a little skeptical about using nio or standard Io. I'm going to try reading the file with both and benchmarking the results. (will share them here too)..Do you have stats as such with your experience.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: No stats really, it will depend on your protocol etc as well. This is another reason to use chunks as if each command is a separate request on a separate connection to the server then you will probably spend as much time setting up sessions as actually sending data.

Comment: Actually I wanted to put on chunk sizes to minimize the interaction with the queue, a thread (that will send request to the server) can take a chunk at ONCE, and process all the records within that chunk by sending requests to the server (based upon the chunk size).
Is that a bad idea?

Comment: 200ms for server to process one record? looks like your bottleneck is going to be at the server side. I would have one thread to read data from disk into buffer and multiple worker threads that gets data from the buffer. So all processing are done by worker threads (ie. parsing the record into specific format to sending to server)

Comment: The thing is i cannot do anything about the server side.it is going to take that long unfortunately :( because it has a lot DB operations etc to be done.. :( 
I as well thought of using executors and reading the stuff from buffer, but there can be overlaps. two threads might just read the same data? [if the request to read comes at the sametime]  I am also  going to have worker threads just that they don't read the data from buffer but a JMS queue (which is fast). Any better ways that you can suggest for hitting the server? Using some framework..its a SOAP interface.

Comment: @user1613403 If the server supports it then sending the chunks to the server as chunks will most likely be faster (again, measure it). If not you will need to break the chunks down and send the individual rows - it's still worth chunking for the threading/queue side of things though.

Comment: @user1613403 To put it into perspective: If the server can only process a single record per 200ms, then that will take ~45 days for 20 million records (obviously using several threads *on the server* can decrease that time linearly). You won't need many threads on your client side to keep the server chugging along (200ms are a *long* time to read data from disk and send it around, a single thread should be able to keep dozens of server threads busy). First order would really be to look at the server code and improve that if possible.

Comment: @Voo Thank you for replying.
I have got 10 Such servers running, so the idea of using n threads is to keep all those 10 servers busy.
I don't want to read the entire file and put it into the memory, so i will be (as you suggested) reading the file in a single Thread, and putting it into the queue. I would have myself loved if the server was capable of processing at a faster rate, but its out of my control :( . Any idea on how can i use the JMS Queue (with multiple threads reading from it ..and only one thread must consume the message, without any bottlenecks) ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could batch the records instead of sending one at a time. You could avoid unnecessary network hops given the volume of data that need to be processed by the server.

Comment: i agree @nithin nambiar, the server on the other end is like a provisioning system, which provisions one record at once ..unfortunately, if i could control that yeah you are right that would have saved a lot of network latency issues.
Thanks so much for the input :)